# Gstreamer: Can't listen to audio + record from alsasrc at the same time?

Tags: c, gstreamer, alsa

I'm writing a C application that uses gstreamer to record audio from a TV tuner.

I have an TV tuner card that have a sound card like hw:1,0.
The audio source is accessed by default as playback source when the application start using ALSA API.

I want to write a function to record sound from this source using GStreamer backend.

My next issue seems to involve a tiny race condition involving my hw:1,0 already being in use and needing to be able to record something.

What can I do to make this work?

UPDATE: Playing sound not use GStreamer API, if alsa and libv4l2util is available, it will automatically start an audio streaming between the V4L2 device (hw:1.0) and the audio output device (hw:0.0) using ALSA functions.

I try to stop ALSA streaming and use a Gstreamer element tee:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GstCaps *filter;

    GMainLoop *loop;
    GstBus *bus;

    GstElement *pipeline, *audiosource, *audiosink, *audioresample, *audiobin, *audiotee, *encodebin, *filesink, *savebin;

    GstEncodingProfile *profile;

    gst_init (&argc, &argv);
    loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("pipeline");
    audiosource = gst_element_factory_make("alsasrc", NULL);
    audiosink = gst_element_factory_make("alsasink", NULL);
    audioresample = gst_element_factory_make("audioresample", NULL);
    audiotee = gst_element_factory_make("tee", NULL);
    encodebin = gst_element_factory_make("encodebin", NULL);
    filesink = gst_element_factory_make("filesink", NULL);

    audiobin = gst_bin_new ("abin");
    savebin = gst_bin_new ("sbin");

    profile = gst_get_encoding_profile(my.settings.profile);

    if (!pipeline || !audiosource || !audiosink || !audioresample || !audiobin)
            return -1;

    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(audiosource), "device", "hw:1,0", NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(filesink), "location", "save.ogg", NULL);
    g_object_set(encodebin, "profile", profile, NULL);
    gst_encoding_profile_unref(profile);

    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(audiobin), "async-handling", TRUE, NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(savebin), "async-handling", TRUE, NULL);


    bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (pipeline));
    gst_bus_add_watch (bus, bus_call, loop);
    gst_object_unref (bus);

    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (audiobin), audiosource, audioresample, audiotee, audiosink, NULL);
    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (savebin), encodebin, filesink, NULL);
    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), audiobin, savebin, NULL);

    filter = gst_caps_new_simple("audio/x-raw", "rate", G_TYPE_INT, 32000, NULL);
    if (!gst_element_link_filtered(audiosource, audioresample, filter))
            return -1;

    if (!gst_element_link_many(audioresample, audiotee, audiosink, NULL))
            return -1;

    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    g_main_loop_run (loop);

    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (pipeline));

    return 0;
}
```

Now I can hear the sound, recording start but created recording file contains no data.

Comment: This is certainly not the full code, the elements ain't even linked and added to the pipeline, and I see no elements for actually playing the sound .. Please update your question with the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

In the updated question, I can see that the encodebin is added to the pipeline, but not linked to the audio tee, that would be your problem. In your current code, with the useless audiobin and savebin, I expect you will also get an error when trying to do that, along the lines of "wrong element hierarchy". Get rid of these two bins and it should work.